# laravel ReflectionException after upload to shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5

I ran into a very anoying problem while working with laravel (version 5.2.45).
I developed a web app on my local network which runs without any problems, but when I try to upload it it throws the error:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280: Class App\Http\Controllers\myClass does not exist
```

eventhough the class is there.

My file structure is something like:

-laravel(where all the files are but the public folder)
    
     -all the public files (root directory)

I fixed the paths inside index.php already and changed the permission of vendor, storage and the database.

inside the routes file I define the routes like:

```
Route::get('/','myClass@index');
```

which works just fine on locahost.

Can anybody help me?